# Create EF models over command line or c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cmd, dynamically-generated, ef-database-first

I'm using EF for database access with database first convention. Is it possible, to generate the entity framework models over c# or the command line? Important is, that no visual studio is required for that.

I've searched but could not find any thing, besides the visual studio ui.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use Visual Studio? If cost is the issue, try using Visual Studio Express for Web. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx Here are the instructions: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database

Comment: @PhilWalton thank you, but we have vs prof/ultimate. I want to generate the models on customer servers and they have no visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure is it helpful for you but you can check [EDM Generator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb387165(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: This seems to be perferct. Thank you, i will check the tool. :)